# What is the ES5 alternative of ES6's tagged template literals?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in ES6 standard :

```
 function test(html, ...args) {
   return html.slice(1).reduce((str, elem, i) => str + args[i] + 
  elem, html[0]);
 }
```

And this to use it :

```
 var hello = 'Hello';
 var world = 'Arcanadian Arc';
 document.body.innerHTML = test`<h1>${hello} ${world}!</h1>`;
```

Output :

```
 <h1>Hello Arcanadian Arc!</h1>
```

As, it's a ES6 standard code, IE doesn't support it. So, I decided to transpile this to ES5 using Babel and that's what I did. But I am not satisfied with the output. Here is the output :

```
function _templateObject() {
   var data = _taggedTemplateLiteral(["<h1>", " I am very happy </h1>"]);

    _templateObject = function _templateObject() {
     return data;
  };

   return data;
 }

  function _taggedTemplateLiteral(strings, raw) { if (!raw) { 
   raw = strings.slice(0); } return Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties(strings, { raw: { value: Object.freeze(raw) } })); }

 function test(html) {
   for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
     args[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
   }

   return html.slice(1).reduce(function (str, elem, i) {
     return str + args[i] + elem;
   }, html[0]);
}
```

And to use it :

```
 var hello = 'Hello';
 var world = 'Arcanadian Arc';
 document.body.innerHTML = test(_templateObject(), hello);
```

It works but its syntax is a bit messy. I wanted to call this something like this by replacing ES6's ${} with a {{ }} or aome other, then it would look like this :

```
var hello = "Hello";
var world = "Arcanadian Arc";
document.body.innerHTML = test`<h1>{{ hello }} {{ world }}!';
```

Output :

```
<h1>Hello Arcanadian Arc!</h1>
```

It looks pretty like ES6 and the main thing, it is not messy like the earlier one. But I don't know how to do that ! Can you help me ? But the question is, can this be done ? Can this be used as an ES6 one's alternative ? Or is there a pollyfill for it ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use the newer version?

Comment: `then it would look like this` and IE wouldn't be able to use that either ... not sure how changing `${...}` to `{{...}}` is in any way better

Comment: As my project has to support older browsers ?

Comment: no, but you mentioned IE

Comment: Thats old versions of IE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something as such with help of regex and replace, but you should be using the latest feature while developing the project leave these quirks for tools like [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) or any other transpiler

```js
var hello = "Hello";
var world = "Arcanadian Arc";

function test(str,args){
  return str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (m,g1)=> args[g1.trim()] || m)
}

console.log(test('<h1>{{ hello }} {{ world }}!</h1>',{hello,world}))
```

Comment: That's far near to what I want. I can go with this !! Thanks a lot